# RowFilter on a DataTable to display in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, rowfilter

I have the following code which doesn't seem to work. In the Page_Load function I populate the DataSet and display the results in a grid view.

```
newsCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL code here", dbConnection);
newsDataSet = new DataSet();
newsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(newsCommand);
newsDataAdapter.SelectCommand = newsCommand;
newsDataAdapter.Fill(newsDataSet, "Bulletins");

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridViewMain.DataSource = newsDataSet;
    GridViewMain.DataBind();
}
```

I have some links which call this function to filter the data (yearID is passed as a parameter):

```
DataTable newsTable = new DataTable();
newsTable = newsDataSet.Tables[0];

DataView dvData = new DataView(newsTable);
dvData.RowFilter = "Year > '" +  yearID + "'";

GridViewMain.DataSource = dvData;
GridViewMain.DataBind();
```

Yet the gridview shows the data it orignally loaded, and not the filtered data. The only thing I can think of is that I'm not using the DataTable in the Page_Load function. What else am I missing?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: `DataTable newsTable = newsDataSet.Tables[0]`, **please**.

Comment: yearID is a parameter which started as a year value to filter data by, but I amended it to a full date.

I've just changed the code in the function to:

newsDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "NewsDate2 > '01/01/2010'";
GridViewMain.DataSource = newsDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
GridViewMain.DataBind();

but it still does the same thing (not filtering the data).

Comment: Just realised the comments box doesn't format code (am new to SO, and have only just returned to ASP, which is why my code might seem a little incorrect).

Answer (score 7):

Changed the code in the function to:

```
DataView dataView = newsDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dataView.RowFilter = "NewsDate2 Like '%" + yearID + "'";

GridViewMain.DataSource = dataView;
GridViewMain.DataBind();
```

It must have been something in the RowFilter statement.

Answer (score 0):

Filter data from **DataTable** and display it in **Gridview**.

```
        string category = ddlcat.SelectedItem.Value; // this can be any input by user
        DataTable dt = filter_dt; //filter_dt is DataTable object, contains actual data, from there we will filter
        DataView dataView = dt.DefaultView;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
            dataView.RowFilter = "Category = '" + category + "'";
        }
        Gridview1.DataSource = dataView;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
```

If any doubt,feel free to ***ask***.

*Thank you*