# C# DatagridView search/filter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am new to c#, I am trying to use filter the datagridview based on combobox value. Initially I loaded datagridview with all the desired values from database, now I want whenever user selects anything from combobox, the values in DataGridView should also change. One Solution which works for me is to request the database on each combobox value change and it works... code is attached for that

```
DataRowView view = (DataRowView)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
int year = (int) view.Row["Year"];
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
    String query = "Select * from yearly where year = "+year;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

but, is there any way to not request the database again and again ? and I can filter the datagridview based on combobox value. Any tutorial or link will work.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449954/rowfilter-on-a-datatable-to-display-in-a-gridview). Also, are you keeping a connection open all the time? That is not good.

Comment: Thanks, no I am not keeping my connection open :) I close it after every execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In combobox's SelectionChangeCommitted event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Year= '{0}'", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives following excecption. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @Nixi What is null? Did you check?

Comment: @Nixi, you can't paste that exactly, your control names are different. Use the answer as a template.

Comment: @BerkayYaylaci Thanks alott :) this solution worked, after finding the null pointer exception ... It was caused because the issue of Combobox.selectedindexchanged ... as I read in documentation this event gets called on loading :) and at that time my datagridview is not ready

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** 
If your data is changing frequently and you want up to date data you are OK to use the same code as yours.

**Solution 2:**
Get the data from datasource - Store into DataTable - Filter the data as per requirement and set DataGridView source to dataset.

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)