# datagridview search not displaying correct answer

Tags: c#, datagridview

When search button is pressed, im trying to count how many results have the same 'username' and then sum their 'earned' (earned is a decimal)

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue = textBox5.Text;
        int rowIndex = 1; 

        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            bool valueResult = true;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    rowIndex = row.Index;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Selected = true;
                    rowIndex++;
                    valueResult = false;
                    var count = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .Count(roww => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == searchValue);
                    this.textBox6.Text = count.ToString();
                }
            }
            if (valueResult != false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record is not avalable for this Name: " + textBox5.Text, "Not Found");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

1) But for some reason `textbox6`would display the last number in 'id' column regardless of username searched
2) Also, I cant figure out how to sum the every cell in 'earned' for that specific user searched

[[Example of datagridview from MySql][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asi0d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asi0d.png)

**Im still a beginner in c#**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DatagridView search/filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077568/c-sharp-datagridview-search-filter)

Comment: Do you mind telling me where exactly could that duplicate be and how to fix it

Comment: This is the type of thing you can easily solve using the **[Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** .  You have a loop going thru all the rows, but the count variable is trying to do it all once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already iterating through the rows with the foreach there's no need to recalculate the count of matches each time within the foreach.  Instead you can increment a counter and add to an earned total for all of the rows that match.

The reason why textbox6 seemed to have the value of the last row's "id" column (which was actually a count of all of the rows in the grid) is because of the Count condition:

```
.Count(roww => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == searchValue)
```

which should be:

```
.Count(roww => roww.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == searchValue)
```

With it as `roww => row` and being within the if condition it would return the count of all rows not just the matched rows.  But again, having the `.Count` is unnecessary.

Here's a modified version that iterates through the rows and increments a counter and adds to the earned total for the rows that match the selection criteria:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue = textBox5.Text;

        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            decimal earnedTotal = 0;
            int matches = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if(!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    if((string)row.Cells[1].Value == searchValue)
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;

                        decimal earned;
                        if (decimal.TryParse((string)row.Cells[2].Value, out earned))
                            earnedTotal += earned;

                        matches++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Selected = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(matches == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Record is not avalable for this Name: " + textBox5.Text, "Not Found");

            textBox6.Text = matches.ToString();
            txtEarnedTotal.Text = earnedTotal.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah I understand now. it worked like a charm! thank you so much.