# How to Search datagridview with textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to search my datagridview with value from a textbox. Here is what I have so far. But it is not doing search the datagridview.

```
    private void TextboxBarcodeNo_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxBarcodeNo.Text))
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ItemCode = '{0}'", textboxBarcodeNo.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are doing [filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077923/1997232). Does filtering works? What you expect to happens by saying "not doing search"?

Comment: You may want to use `LIKE '%{textboxBarcodeNo.Text}%'` or `LIKE '{textboxBarcodeNo.Text}%'` or `LIKE '%{textboxBarcodeNo.Text}'`, possibly using a selector to determine what kind of comparison is performed (*contains*, *starts with* or *ends with*). Is `ItemCode` a string data Type or a numeric data Type?

Comment: it does not filter the data grid

Comment: @Jimi it is a string

Comment: Well, if the data source of the DGV is a DataTable which has a Column named `ItemCode` that is of Type `string`, then there's no reason for the filter to fail. You should handle the `TextChanged` event of your TextBox, not the `Leave` event, of course.

Comment: @Jimi I've changed the code so that it will use the TextChanged event still nothing

Comment: You need to specify and add to the question: the DataSource Type of your DGV, verify and confirm that the DataGridView name is `dataGridView1`, verify and confirm that it has a Column named exactly `ItemCode` and check + confirm that the data type of that Column (in the DataSource) is `string` and not `int` or `long` or whatever else. -- Add these details to your question. -- Note that this is a Filter, not a search operation. Use the `LIKE` operator, as described, not `=`. Also note how `%` is used: e.g., `[...].RowFilter = $"ItemCode LIKE '%{textboxBarcodeNo.Text}%'"` means *Contains*.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks your last comment did really help